# What android layout(s) should I use?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to resize the components when the display screen is smaller / bigger. Two big buttons at the top and at the bottom. 3 another buttons centrally aligned (these should be always 32*32 size remain).

[image]

Comment: The question is extremely narrow, "what type of layout to use". It's not right in my opinion to close it.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev: "Questions asking us to **recommend or find** a book, **tool, software library**, tutorial or **other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow..." (emphasis mine). This question asks what layout OP should use, which implies `recommend or find` and `tool, software library or other off-site resource`. Per definition, layouts are either tools or libraries (depending on included vs external), or fall under the last category when it's neither of the previous one. Closing it is right.

Comment: @Zoe yes, but layout is not a tool, software library or resource. Just some classes in Android API. Seems to be valid question "which layout to use in this case". There are not many of them: LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ConstraintLayout. And it might be not obvious for a beginner how to use LinearLayout correctly in this case, that's why I answered. If stackoverflow is still not a good place to ask such questions, could you recommend another platform?

Comment: @AntonMalyshev I believe this question should remain closed for now as it doesn't show or even hint at what the author has tried.  This is too close to a "please give me the codes" post.

Comment: @Sam sounds to me rather as "please give me some hint" :) and (as my answer is accepted) just a hint was enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do this with two nested `LinearLayout`s.

In the first `LinearLayout` two big buttons should have `layout_gravity` = `top` and `bottom`, `layout_weight` = `1`, `height` = `0px` and `width` = `match_parent`. Also the first layout should have `orientation`=`vertical`.

The second layout for three small buttons should be nested between the two big buttons, have fixed `height` = `32dp`, `width` = `match_parent` and no `layout_weight`.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the Constraint Layout.

1) In your case, your root layout is LinearLayout (vertical)

2) Add 3 layouts of your choice and set "layout_weight" to fit your needs
(default weight sum is 1, so to have 3 sections with the same width, set each to 0.33 If you want top and bottom to take 40% of the screen, set top and bottom layout_weight to 0.4 and the middle section to 0.2

```
[...]
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
[...]
```

3) Layout in the center should be constraint layout.

Place your center element aligned to the center of the screen, then take constraints from there to right and left elements, and from left and right elements to screen border. Then draw constraints to top and bottom of your parent element. Note that with different screen width the spacing between elements will vary anyway.

To vary the spacing of right and left elements, you can try different screen-sizes and change these attributes:

```
android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
```

It is reccomended, if you use icons for your buttons in the center section, to use different sizes and dpi for different screen sizes. Then set height and width of these image Buttons to wrap content. A guide can be found [here](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/).

Image: [image]

Example Code like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"></LinearLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.495"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: wow, downvote without any hint on what is wrong with my answer...thanks!

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your answer. Another valid way to do the thing. People just seem unhappy that we're answering.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a constraint layout and attach the components to the layout so when the layout's size change, the components' size also change